# Stop QGIS plugin execution

Tags: python, qgis-plugins

I made a QGIS plugin but I didn't built it with the current structure because I need to keep the dialog window open during execution. So I didn't use a QDialogButtonBox for "Ok" and "Cancel" button, I just used two QPushButton in order to keep the window opened during execution. My problem is when I click on Cancel the dialog closed but the script keep running.

My code is as following :

```
def __init__(self, iface):
        self.dlg.ANNULER.clicked.connect(self.quitterProgramme)
        self.dlg.OK.clicked.connect(self.exeProgramme)

def exeProgramme(self):
        if programmeExecute == False :
            self.monProgramme()
        else :
            self.quitterProgramme()

def quitterProgramme(self): 
        self.dlg.close()
```

Comment: What about using a **dockwidget** instead a dialog window? This way, the dockwidget can remain open until the user closes it.